# Generate unique code every six hour with wordpress rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest, refresh

I want to generate 12 digit unique code with wordpress rest api which refresh every six hours. I didn't find any code or method for my requirement.

Example URL: ....domainname.com/wp-json/astra-sites/v1/get-last-unique-code

Json code on above link:

```
{"last_unique_code":"4qN6Ixy0&2!H"}
```

This code refresh every six hours. Please give me code or details to generate same code which refresh every six hours.

I know how to do custom "register_rest_route" to create custom api path but I didn't find any method to refresh code automatically with php and wordress.

I am using below code

```
class My_Rest_APIs {
    
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'create_api_posts_meta_field' ) );
    }

    public function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
        register_rest_route('my-custom-pages/v1', 'get-last-unique-code', [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'last_unique_code' )
        ]);
    }

    public function last_unique_code() {
        $pass = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz@#$%&"), 0, 12);
        $checksum = array('last_unique_code' => $pass);
        return $checksum;
    }

}
```

Above code generates unique code but I don't know how to store it in database which refresh every six hours. I tried update_option() method but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: how about a cron job which runs every 6 hours, generates the code and stores it in the database? Then the PHP code which displays it will just get the latest value from the database.

Comment: Or on-the-fly creation, with a _seed_ value for the random generator, that stays constant for each six hour interval.

Comment: Try to use Transient API of WordPress that will helpful to manage time. You cen set,get,delete transient for specific interval of time

Comment: Can you please give me sample code for on-the-fly or cron job so I can try?

Comment: Why, where exactly are you stuck? Is the problem generating the random code? Or inserting into the database? or how to set up a cron schedule? Or something else? Don't just ask us to provide generic code for you (especially when we don't know anything about your existing application or how it would fit in) - instead, break the task down into its constituent parts, research each part and try to understand and implement it. If you get stuck, ask us about your particular issue. We're not a free write-my-code or tutorial service, but we'll _help_ you with a specific, definable programming problem

Comment: P.S. Please review the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and the 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to better understand how the site works and how you should approach your questions.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson for your suggestion. 
This is my first post so I am learning post rules. I added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executed below updated code snippet of yours.
When you run `SITE_URL/wp-json/my-custom-pages/v1/get-last-unique-code` you will find the value of your checksum which will be updated every six hours

```
class My_Rest_APIs {
    
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'create_api_posts_meta_field' ) );
    }

    public function create_api_posts_meta_field() {
        register_rest_route('my-custom-pages/v1', 'get-last-unique-code', [
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => array( $this, 'last_unique_code' )
        ]);
    }

    public function last_unique_code() {
        
        // Get any existing copy of our transient data
        if ( false === ( $pass = get_transient( 'pass_key' ) ) ) {
            // It wasn't there, so regenerate the data and save the transient
            $pass = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz@#$%&"), 0, 12);
            set_transient( 'pass_key', $pass, 6 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
        }

        $checksum = array('last_export_checksums' => $pass);
        return $checksum;
    }

}

new My_Rest_APIs();
```

Comment: Thanks a million, Iqbal. Your code is working perfectly. I appreciate your taking the time to answer my query. It has helped me :)  :)  :)